# What is asymptotic variance and how do I find it?

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

I don't understand the concept of asymptotic variance. Given the mle of a probability function, the likelihood function and the random variables how do I find asymptotic variance?
What exactly is asymptotic variance? I'm finding this concept very confusing.

Comment: Asymptotic variance refers to the variance of a statistic (appropriately normalized by first subtracting the expected value and multiplying by the square root of the sample size) when the sample size approaches infinity. So when the sample size is "large", there is a theoretical reason to believe that the finite-sample variance can be reasonably approximated by the asymptotic counterpart.